# Overload operator+(int) with number before object

Tags: c++

I have a vec2 class, defined like this

```
class vec2 {
public:
    float x, y;

    ...

    //add a scalar
    vec2 operator+(float s) const {
            return vec2(this->x + s, this->y + s);
        }
};
```

The operator+ overload works good when doing `vec2 v = otherVector * 2.0f;` but doesn't work when doing it backwards, like so `vec2 v = 2.0f * otherVector;`.

What's the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Taking your example, the expression

```
otherVector * 2.0f
```

is equivalent to

```
otherVector.operator+(2.0f)
```

Creating an overloaded operator as a member function *only* allows the object to be on the left-hand side, and the right-hand side is passed to the function.

The simple solution is to add another operator overload, as a non-member function

```
vec2 operator+(float f, const vec2& v)
{
    return v + f;  // Use vec2::operator+
}
```